# In Twilio Studio how can I trigger a Flow from a REST API inside a Flow triggered by a message?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-studio

I have a Twilio Studio Flow that's triggered by a message, flow A. In the flow I use an http widget to call my API (Flask App) which triggers another Twilio Sudio Flow via a REST API, flow B. This initiate flow B, but when I reply it triggers flow A rather than executing flow B.

This is because flow A ends after it executes the http widget which calls my API. I don't know the best work around for this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Some details]
Why not use sub-flows? You can only cannot nest sub-flows which is effectively what I am trying to achieve. I've also maxed out my maximum number (10) of unique sub-flows per flow.

I have tried triggering flow B via message, rather than REST API, using webhooks and that works fine. Which I expected. But I need to be able to trigger it from flow A.